# Given bounds of n-th moments, how to bound the probability of a random variable's taking large values?

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

For example, given a positive r.v. $X$, if we know $\mathbb{E}(X)^{n} \leq f(n)$, where $f$ is a function of $n$,  and we know the fact $\mathbb{E}(X^{n}) = \int_{0}^{\infty}n x^{n-1} \mathbb{P}(X > x)dx$. Then can we show $\mathbb{P}(X > x) = O(\frac{f(n)}{nx^{n-1}})$? It is quite intuitive but I don't know if it is true.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I suspect one might be able to make a counterexample by choosing an $X$ that's supported on an incredibly sparse sequence of positive integers: then $P(X>x)$ is constant for very long stretches, which tends to mess up decay statements.

Comment: Assuming that $\mathbb{E}[X^n] \leq f(n)$ (it is not clear where the exponent is atm), then Markov inequality tells us $\Pr(X > x) = \Pr(X^n > x^n ) \leq x^{-n} \mathbb{E}[X^n] \leq x^{-n}f(n)$. Does that help?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Thank you! This really helps